# Get first day in a month from NSCalendar

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, calendar, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have this subset of a method that needs to get day one of the current month.

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];  // returns correctly 28 february 2013
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
components.day = 1;
NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:today options:0];
```

`dayOneInCurrentMonth` then prints out `2013-03-01 09:53:49 +0000`, the first day of the next month.

How do I get day one of the current month?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your logic is wrong: Instead of setting the date's day to 1, you're adding a day to the current date.

Try something like that:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:(NSEraCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit) fromDate:today];
components.day = 1;

NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Comment: Of course! Misread the method name. Thank you! Will accept answer :-)

Comment: Ok, @Fabian Kreiser, I used the code as is and it gives me result: `2015-05-31 21:00:00 UTC`. Today is `2015-06-08 8:36`. It does not returns 1st day, but last from previous month?

Answer (score 1):

You want `[NSCalender dateFromComponents:]` instead:

```
NSDate *dayOneInCurrentMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way of getting to the 1st from a given date:

```
NSDate *first = [gregorian dateBySettingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:1 ofDate:date options:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy Way to get first and last date of previous month is :

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
NSDateComponents *comp = [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay ) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

//TO GET PREVIOUS MONTH LAST DAY
[comp setMonth:[comp month]];
[comp setDay:1];
NSDate *tDateMonth = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
NSLog(@"LAST DAY OF PREVIOUS MONTH ;  %@", tDateMonth);

//TO GET PREVIOUS MONTH FIRST DAY
[comp setMonth:[comp month]-1];
[comp setDay:3];
NSDate *td = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comp];
NSLog(@"FIRST DAY OF PREVIOUS MONTH ;  %@", td);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

By creating new variable is expensive on memory usage, it's better using date formatter to get the first day of the current month

```
today = [NSDate date];

firstDayDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[firstDayDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"01-MM-yyyy"];
dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
firstDayOfTheMonth = [mdfDateFormat dateFromString:[firstDayDateFormatter stringFromDate:today]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDate *startDate = nil;
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth startDate:&startDate interval:NULL forDate:date];

return startDate;
```